# Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED: onReceive() called two times

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, messaging

I have used broadcastreceiver to handle a phone number verification part. It works but in a problematic way.

Issue: 
When there is no message , onReceive() just execute once and return from `if (extras == null){...` part.  this is fine. But if message sent to inbox , `onReceive()` called null i.e `if (extras == null){..` part first(in 1 seconds) and then executes the  original part again(after 3/4 seconds).
Some of my codes:

In onCreate():

```
 receiver = new SMSReceiver();
 filter = new IntentFilter();
 filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
```

In Button Click:

```
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
mProgressDialog = MyProgressDialog.show(RegisterActivity.this, null, null);

SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage(mobileNumber, null, "Verified", null, null);
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

onReceive():

```
private  class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  if(intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){

  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

  if (extras == null){
    _submit.setText("Register");
    _mobile_number.setError("Invalid Number");
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Invalid Mobile Number", ast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
 }

try{

    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
    String origNumber = msg.getOriginatingAddress();
    String msgBody = msg.getMessageBody();

   ..............
```

Am I doing any wrong here ?

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your description, but why are you broadcasting (or attempting to broadcast) the `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` action? This is handled by the system.

Comment: @MikeM. i am working on mobile number verification part. i.e at the time of user registration i have to verify that the user's mobile number is perfect or not by sending a message to its own mobile and handle if the message reached. All I can do by the help of `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast.

Comment: I still don't fully understand, but your app should _not_ be broadcasting that action.

Comment: @MikeM. I am using your answer only. from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133774/use-sms-to-verify-devices-phone-number ..

Comment: Yeah, I figured you were, but nowhere in that post do I broadcast that action. All you need to do is register the Receiver for that action, and send the message.

Comment: But when the verification mobile number is incorrect( i.e new no message in inbox), it just executes once( returning from extra == null)..but when there is a new message(i.e number is perfect), it executes twice..first returning from `extra==null` part and  again executes the same onreceive with perfect one.

Comment: But you told to register in activity:in this sentence... `If you don't need to monitor every SMS received, I would recommend registering it in your Activity for just as long as you need it.`

Comment: Right, register, not broadcast. If the number isn't correct, the device isn't going to receive an incoming SMS, so you'll need to set a time-out for receiving the test message.

Comment: @MikeM. Its good if you show some path in an answer which will help me to understand the problem and resolve. It may helpful for others also.

Comment: I'll update that answer when I'm able to later. I'm on a mobile at the moment. For now, I'd just recommend removing the broadcast, and leaving any dependent functionality disabled until a confirmation SMS is verified.

Comment: @MikeM. Its ok Mike. I am trying to resolve. thanks for your time :)

Comment: In fact, that would be how I'd recommend handling it. There's no need for a timeout. Just don't enable the necessary functionality _until_ the number has been verified.

Comment: Thanks Mike.I got solution from your comments.I think first of all i have to delete 3 main sentences (i.e  `Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
sendBroadcast(i);`). Am I right..

Comment: Yep. That should do it. When you get the incoming SMS and verify the number, then enable whatever you need to.

Comment: @MikeM. Can you help me to do this in dual SIM devices. I am facing problem in here.

Comment: I have asked the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437699/mobile-number-verification-for-dual-sim-devices-in-android

Comment: I've not done anything with dual SIMs before, and the versions of Android I work with don't directly support them. I think Lollipop does, but I've not done anything with that, either.

Comment: No Problem Mike..By the way Thanks for your support :)